# What is the difference between -, -> and --> when querying using Cypher (Neo4j)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have seen different versions of "linking" in Cypher for example:

1. `match (n)-[r]-() delete, n, r`
2. `merge (n) -[:TO {dist:line.distance}] -> (m)`
3. `match (n:MyNode)-[r:TO]->(m) where not ((m)-->())`

where these links can be assigned using 1) "-", 2) "->" 3) "-->", I was wondering what the difference between these three types are. In these different contexts, I see that they are used differently but was wondering if there was a general rule for understanding this.

Answer (score 10):

1. `(n)-[r]-()` means that you do not care about the directionality of the relationship `r`.
2. `(n)-[r]->(m)` means that the relationship `r` must be directed *from* `n` *to* `m`.
3. `(n)-->(m)` means that you do not want to qualify the relationship pattern (e.g., specify a type) nor get any data from the relationship via an identifier (e.g., `r`).

You can read [the documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/match/#relationship-basics) to get more information.